# data is not submitting into db laravel:5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to save data in db but it is not saving ant says 404|not
found

controller:

```
   DB::table('forms')->insert([
        'patient_insurance' => $request->patient_insurance,
        'patient_insurance_id' => $request->patient_insurance_id,
        'patient_reason' => $request->patient_reason,
        'patient_new' => $request->patient_new,
        'patient_message' => $request->patient_message,

    ]);
    return back();
```

route:

```
  Route::resource('form', 'FormController');
```

blade:

```
  <form method="post" action="{{ route('form.store')}}">
```

model:

```
   protected $guarded = [];

   protected $table = "forms";

   protected $fillable= 
   ['patient_name','patient_insurance','patient_insurance_id', 
   'patient_reason', 'patient_new', 'patient_message'];
```

anyone can tell me about the problem

Comment: Post output of `$ php artisan route:list`

Comment: https://ibb.co/w7GT1C6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you supposed to insert your data inside store function on FormController class?

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Patient;
class FormController extends Controller{
    public function store(Request $request){
        $patient = new Patient;
        $patient->patient_insurance = $request->input('patient_insurance');
        $patient->patient_insurance_id = $request->input('patient_insurance_id');
        $patient->patient_reason = $request->input('patient_reason');
        $patient->patient_new = $request->$request->input('patient_new);
        $patient->patient_message = $request->input('patient_message');
        $patient->save();
        return back();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i just added these two line in my controller (use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;) and data started submitting,,, can you explain me what is the mean of this and whats their purpose?

Comment: if you want to save data into db, you need to do it in store function. In previous laravel version it is done so, please read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#basic-controllers